# How to ask esper to call update when there's no result in ON-SELECT query, or other clause

Tags: esper

I want to have a callback whether there are results or not.

The code below aims to find all points in a range.

```
ON QueryEvent e
SELECT w, e FROM DataRecordWindow w
WHERE w.value>e.begin AND w.value<e.end // between-and 
ORDER BY w.value;
```

If there is no result, there would be no callback to invoke UpdateListener, I hope esper to invoke update with parameter null.

I tried InnerJoin, but the result is same:

```
SELECT w, e FROM DataRecordWindow w, QueryEvent e UNIDIRECTIONAL
WHERE w.value>e.begin AND w.value<e.end // between-and 
ORDER BY w.value;
```

My third try is:

```
ON QueryEvent e
SELECT WINDOW(w), WINDOW(e) FROM DataRecordWindow w
WHERE w.value>e.begin AND w.value<e.end // between-and 
ORDER BY w.value;
```

Good, if there are results, return two array, else return two null. Finally, at least, it callback even though there no result.

But i hope it returns me my origin e.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join or a unidirectional outer join.

```
SELECT w, e 
FROM DataRecordWindow w
  full outer join 
  QueryEvent e UNIDIRECTIONAL
WHERE w.value>e.begin AND w.value<e.end // between-and 
ORDER BY w.value;
```